# What are Tier appropriate gold awards for Adventurers League adventures?

Tags: dnd-5e, treasure, dnd-adventurers-league, adventure-writing

[How can I get my adventure published as an Adventurer's League official module?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88646/how-can-i-get-my-adventure-published-as-an-adventurers-league-official-module/90437#90437) describes the process for submitting adventures from conventions to Adventurers League to become certified “legal” CCC-AL adventures.

[What is Tier appropriate treasure for Adventurers League adventures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115048/what-is-tier-appropriate-treasure-for-adventurers-league-adventures) addresses how much *magical* treasure can be awarded.

What are the general guidelines for how much *gold* to award is appropriate per Tier or per hour of adventuring for potentially AL “legal” adventures?

Answer (score 7):

DDAL modules (including CCCs) have three types of treasure - individual, lair, and hoard. Individual treasures appear the most, and have the smallest value. Hoard treasures are large, but only occur with special approval (in non-CCC content, generally only in Epics).

Creating CCC modules requires making contact with the DDAL administration. The specific values you're seeking are included in an information packet provided to prospective authors *after* they register to write modules. While I have the document in question, I'm not at liberty to share it.

With this series of questions, I believe your heart may be in the right place, but you're putting the cart in front of the horse. See the answer to "[How can I get my adventure published as an Adventurer's League official module?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88646/how-can-i-get-my-adventure-published-as-an-adventurers-league-official-module?noredirect=1&lq=1)" for how to go about this the right way. You need to make a proposal *in conjunction* with a convention to the DDAL administration *before* you begin writing.