# How do Author Only Adventures privileges get granted in Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, adventure-writing

***Author Only adventures*** are adventures for Adventurers League (AL) that are written by individuals that can only be run in their own campaigns as Adventurers League official until sold on DMsGuild.

[Robert Adducci mentions on his Patreon page](https://www.patreon.com/RobertAdducci) that he is an Adventurers League administrator and as a result was given the privilege of writing *Author Only adventures.*

Are *Author Only adventures* any different than [Convention Created Content (CCC)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88646/how-can-i-get-my-adventure-published-as-an-adventurers-league-official-module/90437#90437) adventures? (i.e. Is the path to writing an adventure always associated with running a convention?) Have there ever been *Author Only* adventures written by non-AL administrators?

Answer (score 13):

The only people that are granted rights to create Author Only mods were either admins for the D&D AL (Travis Woodall, Bill Benham, Greg Marks, Claire Hoffman, Alan Patrick, and Lysa Chen) or Wizards of the Coast D&D employees and have been run by Mike Mearls, Jeremy Crawford, Chris Perkins, and Chris Lindsay. As a former admin I was given the ok to continue to write and run AO's through 2018.

The Guild Adepts (of which I am also one) also occasionally get permission to run special aspects of their adventures, such as offering certain magic items that tie into their adventures.

Yes, *Author Only adventures* are different than CCC's.

Aside from AL Admins (and former Admins) only Wizards of the Coast employees have written AO's, no one outside has ever been allowed to write them.

Comment: (In case others didn't notice...) Nothing like an answer from Robert Adducci himself!  Thanks Robert -  it adds nice authority to hear from you directly